# I want to retrieve all data from table between two dates

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

[image]

The above screenshot shows table data where ClNum - 97 has three rows of data with different dates. I want to get all dates data for CLNum-97 from

```
EntryDate >= '1-6-2017' to EntryDate <= '30-6-2017'
```

and `order by EntryDate ASC` but retrieve only the last date data.

Please help me out here I want all data of that employee between this two dates.

Comment: HINT.. use between and max, if you want to display all then group by

Comment: Can you just provide me query..?

Comment: well... you have to look it up.. similar cases here

Comment: Post your query in its complete form please. Hard to understand what you are doing wrong.

Comment: SELECT * from TimeSheet where EntryDate between Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,'2017-06-01')) and  Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,'2017-06-30')) and CLNum='97'

Comment: try `( '20170601' <= EntryDate ) and ( EntryDate < '20170630' )`

Answer (score 0):

Because of the system locale in your PC, the date format may be different.

try changing '1-6-2017' to '2017-06-01'
and '30-6-2017' to '2017-06-30'

Comment: set dateformat dmy
SELECT * from TimeSheet where EntryDate between Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,'2017-06-01')) and  Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,'2017-06-30')) and CLNum='97'                            But Geting only one data and i want all data from clNumber='97' between this dates

Comment: its because the data in your database is June, July, August. but what i get from you description is you want to query from 1 June to 30 June.
use select * from Timesheet
  where CLNum = 97
  and EntryDate >= '2017-06-01'
  and entrydate <= '2017-08-30'  
for getting june to august

Comment: Done Thanks a lot i have tried but not working the problem is date format.. i got it... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to use date in the format of yyyy-mm-dd. Try below query. 
May be it solve your problem.

```
Select * from TimeSheet where EntryDate >= '2017-06-01' and EntryDate <= '2017-06-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 1 * from TimeSheet 
where EntryDate between '2017-06-01' and '2017-06-30' and ClNum =97
order by EntryDate desc
```